# CLion method signature doesn't hint

Tags: settings, clion, jetbrains-ide

OS: ArchLinux

IDE: CLion

I tried to get the view of method signature by typing <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd>, also by `View -> Parameter Info`. But it doesn't work.

My settings:

1. Yes -> Show the parameter info popup 1000 ms
2. Yes -> Show full method signature

How can I fix it? May be there are some plugins to get view signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a known issue. Please check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277166 as well as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277041.

There are suggestions about checking the value of `ide.browser.jcef.enabled` option... but a few comments from Linux users say they have it enabled already anyway (which is the  default)...

Follow those tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

You may download custom JDK build or some other tricks there: check [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277041#focus=Comments-27-5197154.0-0) for example.